# How do I use source in podfile?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm new to ios development. For some reason I need to manually set podfile for my Cordova app. There are `GoogleCloudMessaging` and `GGLInstanceID` in my podfile, now I want to install a brightcove video player library, the source is `https://github.com/brightcove/BrightcoveSpecs.git`. However when I add the `source` on the top of podfile, it seems cocoapods also try to install `GoogleCloudMessaging` from that source.

My podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/brightcove/BrightcoveSpecs.git'

use_frameworks!

platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'myapp' do
    pod 'Brightcove-Player-Core/dynamic'
    pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging'
    pod 'GGLInstanceID'
end
```

Error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleCloudMessaging`
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to include the official CocoaPods source:
`https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`

[Docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#source):

> The official CocoaPods source is implicit. Once you specify another source, then it will need to be included.

So your file should work like this I believe:

```
source 'https://github.com/brightcove/BrightcoveSpecs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'myapp' do
    pod 'Brightcove-Player-Core/dynamic'
    pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging'
    pod 'GGLInstanceID'
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Try by giving like:

```
 pod "Brightcove-Player-FreeWheel", :git => 'https://github.com/brightcove/BrightcoveSpecs.git'
```