# Unable to build my (vuejs + capacitor) app with Xcode

Tags: xcode, capacitor

I'm learning to use vueJs/Capacitor to build an app for Android & IOS.
I succeed to build the Android version, but I'm blocked with the IOS version. I tried to many way since yesterday ....

[image]

I'm working under Window 11 & vmWare - MacOS 12.

Under W11 :

- npm install @capacitor/ios
- npx cap add ios
- npm run build
- npx cap sync
- copy the ./myProject/ios folder  to the shared folder

Under MacOS :

- opened App.xcworkspace
- launched build and got the bellow error

If somebody is able to help :)

Edit :

```
npx cap doctor (under Windows 11)
Latest Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/core: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/android: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/ios: 3.3.3

Installed Dependencies:

  @capacitor/cli: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/ios: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/core: 3.3.3
  @capacitor/android: 3.3.3

[success] Android looking great! 
[error] Xcode is not installed
```

Comment: Can you run `npx cap doctor` and share the results?

Comment: Why are you copying to the shared folder? Can you share your Capacitor.config.ts and your angular.json?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I edited the original post to be more readable. I'm working with vueJS and some capacitor modules, I don't have the files Capacitor.config.ts and your angular.json. I copied to a shared folder because I'm working under Windows 11 and I'm using vmWare (MacOS) to build an IOS version with XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by :

- Reinstallations of  Ruby / curl / cocoapods
- error verify_xcode_license_approved! : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60546847/3355901 (solution work with a simple command shell and not with powershell)
- Could not open library 'libcurl' : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520917/3355901
- Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179841/3355901 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/47138575/3355901